# Should slugs and snails be treated the same way?

Tags: plant-care, pests, snails, slugs

I've been reading articles on taking care of plant species such as basil and have noticed that though I've seen precautions for slug infestations, I haven't seen the same for snails. They're both mollusks so I'm wondering if they behave the same or share similar diets that I should be worried about.

anecdote: I was warned about slugs eating my basil leaves, instead i found snails looking like they were eating them. Makes me wonder if I should assume one behaves like the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they behave similarly, but remedies for slugs also work for snails.